# How to back to UIViewController from a NSObject Class in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I have a `UIViewController` Class. In that class I implement a `UIWebView`. On that `WebView` I got data from `CocoaHttpServer` and loading a html page. In `CocoaHTTPServer` have a NSObject Class. In that Class I got one method for pop to previous Screen. How to Pop to view controller from `NSObject` class.

This is my `NSObject` class

```
 if([[array lastObject] compare:@"back-button-clicked"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    [self handleBackActionRequest];
}

-(void)handleBackActionRequest
{
    PGSoftApViewController *softAP = [[PGSoftApViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [softAP webToBackNativeCall];
}
```

This is in my `ViewController` class :

```
-(void)webToBackNativeCall
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This is not working. I am able to insert **webToBackNativeCall** method. But its not happening anything.

I have to go back. How can I. Please help me.

Comment: You can achieve same with @protocol and delegate concept.

Comment: Please can u give some pinch of code ?

Comment: Are you presenting the webView in present ViewController ?

Comment: @BharathRaj : yes I am adding webview in present View controller. ...

Comment: remove web view from super view
[webView removeFromSuperView];

Comment: When have to remove ? When I pop to view controller ?

Comment: Its crashing...Result is : Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

Answer (score 0):

In your NSObject.h class add protocol like this

```
@protocol nsobjectDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)navigateToBackVC;
@end

@interface objectClass:NSObject 
//your other code
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<nsobjectDelegate> objDelegate;
@end
```

In you NSObject .m class

```
-(void)webToBackNativeCall
{
    // this method you already have 
    // other code if you want
    [self.objDelegate navigateToBackVC];
}
```

In you view controller .h class

```
@interface objectClass:NSViewcontroller <nsobjectDelegate> // delegate of NSObject include it in VC when you want to call that methods
```

In you view controller .m file in viewDidLoad or willAppear or DidAppear method initializ object of NSObject class and set delegate

```
NSObjectClass *objeObject = [[NSObjectClass alloc] init]; 
objeObject.objDelegate = self;
```

implement this method

```
-(void)navigateToBackVC
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This is general concept of protocol and delegate.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: I didn't understand... Can you please explain it? you assign deledate =  self ?  Your method handleBackActionRequest is in nsobject class? if yes than you can replace navigateToBackVC your handleBackActionRequest method.

Comment: Yes  @protocol nsobjectDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)navigateToBackVC;
property (nonatomic,weak) id<nsobjectDelegate> objDelegate;

Comment: Yes this is step 1; now step 2 in VC files. Include delegate and assign to self and then call that object class.

Comment: HTTPConnection *objeObject = [[HTTPConnection alloc] init];
    objeObject.objDelegate = self;

-(void) navigateToBackVC
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

Comment: Its not coming to this method : navigateToBackVC ... in view controller class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116446/discussion-between-s-r-nayak-and-ajay-gabani).

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad of your ViewController

```
[[myNSOBjectClass alloc] startViewController:self];
```

In NSObject Class

```
@interface myNSOBjectClass{
  //Global access to the view controller. 
  UIViewController *viewController; 
}

@implementation myNSOBjectClass

//function that the caller calls to pass their UIViewController

- (void)startViewController:(UIViewController *)callerViewController{
    viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
   //puts the caller's view controller to the global member.
    viewController = callerViewController;  
}
```